# How to change type of property of extended parent class in a child class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Maybe this is a silly question however I wanted to achieve as follow.

I have a parent class with many properties that I use as a model in my angular project. However, I want to create one more class that have these all properties, but among them, one property should contain different type. How should I achieve?

So here I have a class called Orders

```
export class Orders {
    public id: string;
    public version: string;
    public status: string;
    public name: string;
    public icon?: string;
    public steps?: FlowStep[];
    public sequence: Sequence[]; <----- I want to change type of this
    public start: Trigger;
    public context: Context;
}
```

Now I need one more class for another method, that requires  `public sequence: string[]`. So I tried as follow.

```
export class NewOrders extends Orders {
    public sequence: string[]; <-- Error: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Sequence[]'.
}
```

I know I can define or condition `public sequence: Sequence[]  | string[]` in `Orders` class. But I really don't want to do that, because then `Orders` class will accept data of both type  `Sequence[] and string[]`

Comment: I don't think this should be possible. If you have a class that handles `Orders` then based on [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) it should also handle `NewOrders`, however this violates that.

Comment: So is there any other way to achieve this, I don't want to write all the properties in a new class

Comment: I would do something like `type NewOrders = Omit<Orders, 'sequence'> & { sequence: string[] };` however since you seem to be targeting TS 2.0 (based on your tags) I don't know how you'd write the equivalent since Omit was only added in 3.4 and is based on conditional types added in 2.8